# Custom component updating first object value if we used multiple time in same page

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I create this custom component.  the component name is "Datetimepicker" where i created on method to get the value from js code and set the value in the value

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@inject ILogger<DatetimePicker> _logger;

<div class="input-date-wrap input-date-range-wrap float-end">
    <input id="@ID" type="text" Margin="Margin.Dense" theme="Info" class="form-control" Label="Select Date Range" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
    <svg class="v1-icon v1-icon-calendar">
        <use xlink:href="/images/icon-sprite.svg#calendar"></use>
    </svg>
</div>


@code
{

    private DateRange _value;

    [Parameter]
    public bool IsRanges { get; set; } = false;

    [Parameter]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public DateRange TValue
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value == value) return;
            this._value = value;
            TValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this._value);
        }
    }

   
    [JSInvokable("SetDateRange")]
    public void SetDateRange(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return;

            var dateFrom = DateTime.Parse(text.Split("-")[0]);
            var dateTo = DateTime.Parse(text.Split("-")[1]);

            TValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? new DateRange() : new DateRange(dateFrom, dateTo);
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            TValue = new DateRange();
        }
    }

    [Parameter] 
    public Action ParentMethod { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<DateRange> TValueChanged { get; set; }

    protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var dotNetReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);

            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("SetDotNetObjectforDatetimepicker", dotNetReference);

            await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("InitDatetimePicker", IsRanges, ID);
        }

    }

}
```

and using this in other component

```
  <DatetimePicker ID="usagedaterange"  @bind-TValue="_dateRange" IsRanges="true"></DatetimePicker>
   <DatetimePicker ID="usagedaterange"  @bind-TValue="_dateRange2" IsRanges="true"></DatetimePicker>
```

but when i change date the "_dateRange" always going updating event when i select datw from second datetime picker

i created custom common component in blazor and need to update the value that is bind to that